# Calling Javascript function with variables as parameters

Tags: javascript, variables, parameters

How can I call a javascript function and pass some variables to be used as parameters
for instance

Say the function `javascriptFunction` uses 2 parameter. I will usually call it  as  `javascriptFunction("param1", "param2")` (with single quotes around the strings). But now I want to pass it some variables.

```
string y = "this is a string"
string x = "another"
javascriptFunction(y, x)
```

I have tried `javascriptFunction(@y, @x)`, javascriptFunction("@y", "@x") (with single and then double quotes around the strings) but this does not work

EDIT
I am actually making the call through a view (cshtml file). So my variables are strings.

Comment: It's always good to start learning new language with [some tutorials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference).

Comment: The issue is that I do not create or initialize my variables in the javascript file but an cshtml page that uses strings

Comment: Part of me wants to close this question for being so basic, but I know this is exactly the type of question that SO is made to answer. There must be a duplicate somewhere, but I can't find it.

Comment: We'll need to see more code.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript has a weak type system. There's no need to specify the types. All variables' types are determined by their values. They are created with the keyword `var`:

```
var y = "this is a string";
var x = "another";
```

<sub>[And don't forget to use semicolons!]</sub>

Comment: Semicolons are not necessary though.

Comment: Not to mention that you could use a comma after the first string (in place of a semi-colon) and omit the second `var`.

Comment: @VisioN why did you make it so small now??

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
var y = "this is a string", x = "another";
javascriptFunction(y, x);
```